# Algorithm to generate global (Application scoped) unique request id based on HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets, request, guid, uniqueidentifier

I have issue with generating global unique request id based on HttpServletRequest. I need to make sure the generated id is unique in Application scope. Java UUID Or Random does not guarantee what I want although the chance for duplicate is very low.

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Random` definitely doesn't guarantee uniqueness, but `UUID` definitely does that. So your concern makes no sense. Even if you've hardware capable of serving a billion HTTP requests per second, you'd only after 100 years reach 50% chance on a duplicate.

If you have really really a hard head in this, just check in synchronized block if the application scope contains already such a key and if so, then just generate another one. And so on. This way you can even use `Random`.

#### See also:

- [How unique is UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will go with Random and checking the ID (Key) if it existing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to be absolutely sure you don`t make a duplicate you could use an auto increment database id, but given the incredibly low chances of duplicates using UUID i dont think it justifies the cost.

Comment: Thanks. I think we can use combination of db sequence and random since I want the id is secured.