# How to generate an unique ID for an class instance in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a class that needs to write to a file to interface with some legacy C++ application.
Since it will be instantiated several times in a concurrent manner,
it is a good idea to give the file an unique name.

I could use System.currentTimemili or hashcode, but there exists the possibility of collisions.
Another solution is to put a `var` field inside a companion object.

As an example, the code below shows one such class with the last solution, but I am not sure it is the best way to do it (at least it seems thread-safe):

```
case class Test(id:Int, data: Seq[Double]) {
    //several methods writing files...
}

object Test {
  var counter = 0

  def new_Test(data: Seq[Double]) = {
    counter += 1
    new Test(counter, data)
  }
}
```

Comment: use uuids perhaps? I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it is a good idea to give the file an unique name

Since all you want is a file, not id, the best solution is to create a file with unique name, not a class with unique id.

You could use [`File.createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29):

```
val uniqFile = File.createTempFile("myFile", ".txt", "/home/user/my_dir")
```

[Vladimir Matveev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788207/vladimir-matveev) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579725/how-to-generate-an-unique-id-for-an-class-instance-in-scala/21579896#comment32605701_21579896) that there is a better solution in Java 7 and later - [Paths.createTempFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29):

```
val uniqPath = Paths.createTempFile(Paths.get("/home/user/my_dir"), "myFile", ".txt"),
```

Comment: Or, even better, [`Paths.createTempFile(Paths.get("/home/user/my_dir"), "myFile", ".txt")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)), if you're using Java 7 and later.

Comment: Why you write here `Paths.createTempFile`, shouldn't it be `Files.createTempFile` ?

Answer (score 34):

Did you try this :

```
def uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
```

See [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) javadoc, and also [How unique is UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid) for a discussion of uniqueness guarantee.

Comment: I've looked at that, but it seems to be not guaranteed to be unique.