# Is r.uuid() guaranteed to be unique?

Tags: rethinkdb

Is [`r.uuid()`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/uuid/) guaranteed to be unique?

> Return a UUID (universally unique identifier), a string that can be used as a unique ID.

How **universal** is `r.uuid()`? Is it scoped to a table/database/instance of RethinkDB? Or is it simply computing the hash of a random byte sequence (e.g. `/dev/rand`)? Or does it hash nano-unix time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the answers to a related question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid).

UUIDs are supposed to be uniques because of the very low probability of colisitions. Although in theory they may not be uniques as it's a random algorithm that generates the UUIDs, you will hardly generate a duplicate.

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates) they say that for `68,719,476,736` generated UUIDs (Which it's a very huge number for a common application) you have `0.0000000000000004` for an accidental clash. *It's almost impossible..*

Answer (score 0):

UUID means universally unique identifier. In this context **the word unique should be taken to mean "practically unique" rather than "guaranteed unique"**. Since the identifiers have a finite size, it is possible for two differing items to share the same identifier. This is a form of [hash collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science)).

Anyone can create a UUID and use it to identify something with reasonable confidence that the same identifier will never be unintentionally created by anyone to identify something else.

A UUID is simply a 128-bit value.

Comment: I'm aware of the definition, though I'm curious as to the source of the randomness for `r.uuid()` in particular.

Comment: Then we need to explore source code in detail (https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/next/src/containers/uuid.cc)