# Searching from millions data from array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, search

I am working with **laravel**. I have 1 million data in a database. I am storing as random string. I need to search newly generated Random string so that it won't get repeated.
I am taking all the string in a array from database and searching the newly generated string from php `in_array()`, but it taking to much time .
suggest me the efficient way to search from array or any other way so that string won't get repeated.

Answer (score 2):

Don't take all the strings into array. Just do a query to verify if the next string you want to insert already exists. Something like:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM random_strings 
WHERE random_string = '$newRandomString';
```

If this query returns `1` then you can show a message that the random string already exists.

**Notes**

1. You must add an unique index to the `random_string` field.
2. The query above is just an example to help you understand the solution. You may use `Eloquent` to do the query.

Comment: Its somewhat better but not as per my requirement. when I am inserting the data into the database then after 1300 string it taking 8-10 sec to insert a new string after checking . please tell me some other way which can check and insert data in less time

Answer (score 0):

Make your random string column in the database a `UNIQUE KEY`.

If a new insert fails with a *duplicate key error* then retry it with a second random string.

---

Better yet, read up on UUIDs:  [How unique is UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid)