# How to generate a random ID that is not already in a list in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a list of cues for a movie playback system.

Every time a cue is created I want to add an `id` to the cue object.

(Which looks something like)

```
{
    "name": "Cue One",
    "length": 5000,
    "id": xxx
}
```

Each cue object will get stored in a list of cues.  However, I want to know the best way to generate `ids` for each cue since they will ultimately be looked up, in the list, by ID.

I know I could do something like (`max[cue.id for cues in cuelist] + 1`) or I could use the `random` module and check to see if the `randint` is not in the cues id, however I do not know what the most "legit" way to do this is.

Is there some specific technique or algorithm for this sort of problem?

Comment: Why not use [uuid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) to generate your ids?

Comment: Why not store the cues in a `list`. The `id` field becomes redundant when you can look them up by index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are UUIDs Refering to python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html

Comment: Just a small addition: UUID are not guaranteed to be unique, but that chance that they aren't is negligible.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly how negligible?

Comment: @Startec: [don't worry about it negligible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid), unless you combine UUID version 4 with a bad RNG.