# How To Give A Random File Name To File , Which i am Uploading?

Tags: java, spring

I am uploading a file to a folder , i had given the file name as "1.jpg" , so when i am uploading a new file it will overwrite the existing one,
So How i can give a random file name to the file which i am uploading

MY UPLOAD CODE IS HERE

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event/uploadFile",headers=("content-type=multipart/*"), method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes ={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    //String quote_upload=C:\fakepath\images.jpg
    public @ResponseBody
    String uploadFileHandler(

            @RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("Creating the directory to store file");

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();


                // Creating the directory to store file
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator+"1.jpg");
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                System.out.println("************Server File Location="
                        + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

                //return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("************failes"+ e.getMessage());
                //return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
            //return "You failed to upload " + name
                    //+ " because the file was empty.";
        }
        System.out.println("hello");
        return "hello";
    }
```

Comment: One option is to append current time (up to seconds) and random number generator from `Random`.

Comment: You can use `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()` method to create unique name for `serverFile`

Answer (score 5):

If you do not expect the names to have any sensible order, I would probably go with [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). Something like this should do it:

```
String filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

If you're worried about uniqueness of the UUID, have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid). In short, you are *extremely* unlikely to ever get two ids that are the same.

Answer (score 3):

1. Generate a Random Name for your newly uploaded file

   `String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()+YOUR_FILE_EXTENSION;`
2. Check if File exist in the directory you are uploading

   `if(serverFile.exists())`
3. If File Exist start again from step 1 until you get a file name which is not present in the server.

**Note:** This is not the optimal solution but will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

It will return the time in milliseconds.
If you are not sure about this append some random number to it.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```
File.createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)
```

As the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) states:

> Creates a new empty file in the specified directory, using the given prefix and suffix strings to generate its name. If this method returns successfully then it is guaranteed that:
>
> 1. The file denoted by the returned abstract pathname did not exist before this method was invoked, and
> 2. Neither this method nor any of its variants will return the same abstract pathname again in the current invocation of the virtual machine.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply get a random large integer and give your file that name, like so:

```
String fileExtension = ".jpg";
String fileName = Integer.toString(new Random().nextInt(1000000000)) + fileExtension;
```

Comment: This can lead to duplicates.. nextInt can return duplicate values..