# Not Replace Screenshot file in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Someone knows how I can save screenshots without replacing the existing one.
That is, I need to keep all the photos of the test cases to be used as evidence.

I have tried with the following scomandos:

- StoreEval / new Date (). GetDate () / date
- StoreEval / new Date (). GetMonth () / month

But only saves the capture of this form "photograph (15) .jpg" when I use getdate or "photograph (7)" when I use getmonth, and when running the test case again, the system replaces the same-

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below code. I am using N-unit and selenium C#. You can use it as per your requirement.

```
            Screenshot ScreenImage = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
            string Date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            string TimeNow = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString().Replace(":", "_");
            string FolderPath = Your Path where you want to save the screenhot + "\\" + Date;

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                dir.Create();
            }

            ScreenImage.SaveAsFile(FolderPath + "\\" + "Test" + "_" + TimeNow + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: I am using html to generate the cases.
Will there be a way to do it with that format ??

Answer (score 0):

By Assuming you are using `Java` with `selenium IDE`.

You can use [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) to generate the random number.

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String screenShotFileName = imageLocation + uuid + ".png";
```

Refer [How unique is UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid) to know how unique it is.

Comment: I am using html to generate the cases.
Will there be a way to do it with that format ??