# Is JWT in URI a bad practice?

Tags: http, jwt

I have a backlist of tokens (JWT) stored in Redis and would like to enable users of my website to blacklist their tokens in a RESTful way.

I can either:

1. Build the route `/sessions/<token>` with a DELETE method
2. Build the route `/sessions/` with a DELETE method and the token sent in the request body.

The first solution is simple but the token is stored in the server's logs and in the user's browser's history.

The second solution seems better but I'm not sure I'm not breaking HTTP RFC's idempotency principle by sending a DELETE request with a body.

What's the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is JWT in URI a bad practice?

JWT tokens are URL-safe when it comes to the *syntax*. From the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519):

> A JWT is represented as a sequence of URL-safe parts separated by period (`.`) characters.  Each part contains a base64url-encoded value. [...]

However, when using JWT as *bearer tokens*, it's advisable to avoid sending them in the URL. See the following quote from the [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750):

> Don't pass bearer tokens in page URLs:  Bearer tokens SHOULD NOT be
> passed in page URLs (for example, as query string parameters).
>
> Instead, bearer tokens SHOULD be passed in HTTP message headers or
> message bodies for which confidentiality measures are taken.
>
> Browsers, web servers, and other software may not adequately secure
> URLs in the browser history, web server logs, and other data
> structures.  If bearer tokens are passed in page URLs, attackers might
> be able to steal them from the history data, logs, or other unsecured
> locations.

---

For the situation mentioned in your question, you may not need to send the full token. You could give the token a unique identifier (stored in the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim) and then send only the token identifier to the server.

See how the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim is defined in the above mentioned RFC:

> [**4.1.7.  "jti" (JWT ID) Claim**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7)
>
> The `jti` (JWT ID) claim provides a unique identifier for the JWT.
> The identifier value MUST be assigned in a manner that ensures that
> there is a negligible probability that the same value will be
> accidentally assigned to a different data object; if the application
> uses multiple issuers, collisions MUST be prevented among values
> produced by different issuers as well.  The `jti` claim can be used
> to prevent the JWT from being replayed.  The `jti` value is a case-
> sensitive string.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

A [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) should be [unique enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1155008/1426227) to identify your tokens without collisions.

You don't need to store the full token in the blacklist either: store only the value of the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim and some other claims that you may find relevant (such as [`sub`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2) and [`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4), for example).

---

[`DELETE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) requests shouldn't contain a body. So you could use `DELETE /sessions/{id}`, where `{id}` is the unique identifier of your token.

Comment: If we are going to use JWT Token as an access Token and we are exposing the JWT token in a public url. Do you think still it's a security issue ?