# Should the token be in the route?

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, jwt

I saw a route containing the token in an Asp.net project. I do not code in the backend but it is not looking safe.
I am not sure whether to do such things.

```
 [HttpGet("{id}/{token}")] `
 ...
```

If this is not good practice, how would I work with the HTTP-Headers? If I send the token with the Headers, how would/should I receive and work with the token?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not recommended at all. The token should be placed in the headers and you can access it for example with `[FromHeader]` binding, or in .net Core 2+ with

```
var token = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's [not good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56273618/is-it-bad-to-pass-jwt-token-as-part-of-url).

Ususally you send the token in the [`Authorization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Use) header of your request, e.g.:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ.....
```

in your controller on backend side, you decorate methods or the whole controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
...
```

A middleware will take care of the rest, which means it checks if the token is there and validates it and also sends a response when there's no token or an invalid/expired token. In your controller code, you don't need to handle the token directly. [Here](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/authentication-and-authorization-in-web-api/) is a short introduction to the topic.