# Unique identification value in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I want to generate a unique value, or uuid, (I do not care if it is a number or hex) for some script produced documents in a python3 script, but this should be unique between multiple executions of the script.

etc. The script might run every two (2) or three (3) days. I do not want to get the same uuid twice.

A simple yet practical way I thought of is using the epoch time (since the script won't run twice at the same second) and the machine it will be running will be 64bit ([2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)), but it seems to simple to be foolproof.

Another way to achieve this would be to use [uuid4()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4). Will this be unique between executions and different machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uuid4()` is cryptographically guaranteed to be unique. In practice, you can go so far as to assume that every UUID ever generated is unique.

I refer you to this: [How unique is UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid?rq=1)

Comment: Perfect, so just to be sure, using it is safe between executions right?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 2):

As @Chris Conlan mentions, uuid4() would be unique with almost certain probability. But, you can also name the files with the UNIX timestamp, i.e, the output of `time.time()`.