# how to get the current timestamp using the current date,time,seconds,milliseconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Get the Current Timestamp using js and try to append the current date, time, seconds, milliseconds in a single string

For Example: 2912019121216174

29-1-2019 -This Represents the current date.
12:12:16:174 - this Represents the current time,seconds and its milliseconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: have you tried doing it yourself?

Comment: check this  http://jsfiddle.net/mobiandy/fqc140bz/24/

Answer (score 2):

Hurrah!! Within few minutes i got the excepted result what i have except.

HTML

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
var currentDate = new Date();

var date = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth(); //Be careful! January is 0 not 1
var months = (month+1);
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
var hours = currentDate.getHours();
var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentDate.getSeconds();
var milliseconds = currentDate.getMilliseconds();

var dmy = (""+date+months+year+hours+minutes+seconds+milliseconds);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dmy;
```

Comment: What are you using this for? Date returns a `ticks` or milliseconds since a set date. If you are after a unique ID then this would be better.

Comment: Hi Bibberty, I am using this for Unique ID.

Comment: Hello @Sivakumar, you can just use UUIDv4 for unique id purposes.
Check this answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid

Comment: And is you really need Date.now() which returns milliseconds.

Comment: Yes Bibberty, Date.now() gives the unique value but i cant able get the exact what i need  so i used above method to get the unique id.