# what are the chances for this random unique Id generator to collide?

Tags: python, django, uuid

i want to know what are the chances for this unique id generator to collide
https://github.com/vejuhust/blog-code/blob/master/python-short-id-generator/short_id_v5.py

i wanted to generate a unique url for my Django project. is it going to be safe to use. i am a beginner in python and Django.

Comment: you can use [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html), which is very safe and minimal chance of collision. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid

Comment: i want url to be short

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a base62 encoded 8 *byte* random number. The encoding does not matter however, since every random number is encoded differently. It thus boils down on what are the odds that two 8 byte random numbers are the same.

We can generate a total of *2<sup>8×8</sup>=18'446'744'073'709'552'000* values with 8 bytes. So the odds of generating a second value that is the same is *1/18'446'744'073'709'552'000* or 0.000000000000000000542%.

If you generate *k* items, the odds of generating a duplicate is:

1 - (2<sup>8×8</sup>)!/((2<sup>8×8</sup>-k)!×2<sup>8×8×k</sup>).

As *k* grows larger, the odds of a collision increase. If you mark the field unique, and thus have a retry mechanism, the odds that it will collide a second time (or a third time) are quite small.

Comment: so is it safe to use it as url generator.

Comment: @maria: yes, although as said, you can simply mark the field unique and have a retry mechanism to insert in the database. That will *guarantee* uniqness. But it would be very unlikely to retry anyway.