# Generate Full UUID from UUID Parts

Tags: url, uuid

I have working on some data mining from a game memory, it includes some link with UUID path. Unfortunately, I can only got a small part of the URL because it's already replaced/removed/unloaded from the memory. I want to recover the full UUID path from that, but I wonder is it really possible?

Upon hours of surfing on internet, I can't find a source that covers my problem. The UUID path is really important because its where the server serve the content files. The server will look like this:

```
www.web.com/en-us/store/pdp?id=[UUID]
```

Now the UUID I got looked like this:

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx8-492e-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Where the "X" is unknown because it's already unloaded from the memory. I know it's extremely limited but can we generate any possible full UUID from that small part? So far, the only thing I can think of is using a path finder but another problem arises. An available path finder from GitHub requires some wordlist.txt which mean it can't find any random UUID path.

Comment: There's no way to do that.

Comment: First of all, thank you for correcting my grammar xD. However, is it possible to find paths of web without using a wordlist? @jonrsharpe

Comment: No. And your word list would be "all possible UUIDs" which would be very long and have multiple matches for any given snippet. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1155008/3001761.