Is there a way to disable the Elasticsearch ID Uniqueness check?
I have a project that creates elasticsearch index. I'm trying to increase write speed.
I have read something about auto-generate ids.
Allowing Elasticsearch to generate ids on your behalf should increase document creation speed since Elasticsearch won’t need to check for uniqueness.
I can't use that because i need my own ids to search data but I can guarantee that the ids I produce are unique. Is there a way to disable uniqueness checking so I can look at the impact on performance?

If your index is always insert (never update/upsert), then you can just use their ids (UUID) and include your id as an indexed field.  You can still search on it as needed.
The trick is if you need to update a document based on your id, you will need to see if the document is already in the index, which will require that uniqueness check, and you might as well keep the existing id and take advantage of the automatic uniqueness constraint and segment merge process.

I need my own ids. Because im using it to fetching data with _doc/id .

Yeah, if you need it to be a fetch and not a search then you definitely are going to need to keep the uniqueness check.  Kind of by definition it has to do a unique check so it knows how to index the doc.   The reason it can skip this using UUID is because they are effectively unique (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid) by nature of such a large address space.  Your IDs have no such promises, so it has to do the unique-check.
