# How to create unique file name?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I copy image files from one folder to another with help of `File.Copy()` method.

I need to give unique file name to the copied  image file before it is pasted to the folder.

Any idea how I can implement this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602578/c-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-generate-a-unique-filename

Comment: I don't think that's an exact duplicate, because it asks for the *fastest* way, which probably isn't the best, most simple and maintainable way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Path.GetTempFileName`

more info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.100).aspx

a quote from the link:

> "Creates a uniquely named, zero-byte temporary file on disk and returns the full path of that file."

Comment: This would be good for creating a temp file to write temp data in to. It is not ideal for simply generating a unique name.

Comment: @HackSlash correct. My answer is not the correct one since the file can be deleted as it is a temporary file. (Upvoted the better answers below)

Answer (score 5):

Eyossi's answer should be the accepted solution but another alternative:-

You could use a [guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) to create a unique name *("Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.")*:

```
Dim filename As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString + ".png"
```

Comment: Sorry - I was working in C#. I think my brain must have automatically removed the Dim *** As String :-)

Comment: A GUID was not designed for this purpose where `Path.GetRandomFileName()` was. The result is a similarly incomprehensible string.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to do it

```
fileName = User_Appended_File_Name & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss")
```

It would create a fairly identifiable File Name, with the added advantage of knowing when it was created, a big ol' timestamp.

edit: It will not work if the file saving rate is faster than 1second.

Comment: This fails completely if two files are created in the same second, which could happen quite frequently.

Comment: ^ agreed but for scenario's that take longer than a second (ie exporting to excel file format on a local PC) this works well. Plus you can sort the files in the folder grouped by file type.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using `Path.GetRandomFileName()`.

The previously accepted answer was to use `Path.GetTempFileName` which creates a file. This is not ideal when that file is going to be the target of a file copy operation, as stated in the question.

> Unlike GetTempFileName, GetRandomFileName does not create a file. When
>   the security of your file system is paramount, this method should be
>   used instead of GetTempFileName.

**SOURCE:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

**EXAMPLE:**

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName()
        Console.WriteLine("Random file name is " & fileName)
    End Sub

End Module

' This code produces output similar to the following:   
' Random file name is w143kxnu.idj
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use current date-time as the file name.

Comment: You should note that this would fail if two files are created during the same second, or whatever the smallest time increment indicated by the timestamp is.