# System.IO.IOException: "The file exists" when using System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() - resolutions?

Tags: c#, .net

One of my customers got an exception whenever he tried to use my product. I obtained the callstack of the exception that had occurred, the top of which is:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   at System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
   at System.Windows.Input.Cursor.LoadFromStream(Stream cursorStream)
   at System.Windows.Input.Cursor..ctor(Stream cursorStream)
```

Googling this, I found plenty of [blog posts](http://michaelellerbeck.com/2012/02/14/when-creating-a-temp-file-system-io-ioexception-the-file-exists-error/) stating this exception is thrown when there are more than 65535 temp files in the %TEMP% folder, and that the solution is to simply clear out the old temp files. I can ask the customer to do that, but this might only be a temporary solution - what if they are regularly running some other piece of software that makes frequent calls to GetTempFileName, which will make the problem reoccur over and over?

I can't just programmatically clear out the %TEMP% folder, as that might somehow damage something else, and I can't avoid calling GetTempFileName (and using my own temp folder instead) as it's not me but WPF code that's calling it.

Is there any permanent solution for this?

**UPDATE**: I've confirmed that the problem where the %TEMP% folder is overflowing with log files is not caused by my own code, and must be caused by some other 3rd party application on the customer's machine. I also looked into the implementation of `Cursor.LoadFromStream` and it surely isn't at fault - it generates a temp file, but then deletes it in `finally` block.

Comment: You could make your own "Temp" folder that gets deleted (in application data") but probably would be a ballache to change all references, good question

Comment: The question isn't related to WPF, removed tag. Also, why just don't fix the code, which produces so many temporary files without deletion?

Comment: @Sayse I can't do that because it's WPF's `Cursor.LoadFromStream` that's generating the temp file. @Dennis It's related to WPF's `Cursor.LoadFromStream` class. The offending code which produces so many temporary files without deletion might not even be my own, and I'd still need to address the exception.

Comment: Can you find out which application is leaving behind all these temp files? Is it your application? If WPF is creating these temp files itself have you confirmed that it is deleting them when they are no longer needed?

Comment: @OmerRaviv I think your only option then is to try/catch the IOE, and ask the user if they want you to delete temp files and try again

Comment: It's a more general problem than 'fixing your code', I've noticed similar behavior with Octopus deploy 3.1.3 that fails to clean up after itself. I have to manually delete the temp files folder for the same reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I mentioned in my last comment I think your only safe way to do this is to ask the user if they want you to delete files and try again. It is *imperative* that you get the users input into this, this way it is at their own peril. In my head its something similar to.

```
public Stream GetStream(Stream cursorStream)
{
    try
    {
       //getting stream
    }
    catch(IOE)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, "Unable to get stream, your temporary
                              folder may be full, do you want to try deleting 
                                some and try again?");
         if(yes)
         try
         {
             //delete and try again
             return GetStream(cursorStream);
         }
         catch(IOE)
          {
                //no luck
           }
          else
              return null;
    }

}
```

An optional check to make sure could be,

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.GetTempPath(), "*", SearchOption.TopLevelOnly)
  .Count() == ushort.MaxValue;
```

Comment: I'm gonna go with a try/catch as you suggested. The boolean test you suggested is actually wrong - it's likely there are other files in the %TEMP% folder, besides those in the "tmpXXXX.tmp" format that GetTempFileName() uses, so your test may return true when there's actually no problem and false when there IS a problem.

Comment: The test was designed to find all files in a temp folder (albeit I admit it may not be the right temp folder) and sees if that equals 65535, `"*"` will find all files (regardless of if they have a extension or not) hope it helps

Comment: You could delete all files older than, say, one day. A temporary file older than one day is unlikely to be in use by any other application.

Comment: Just another point on the optional check.  When I ran into this issue on a build server, the temp directory had more than 65535 files. That count only works if the ONLY thing creating temporary files is through the Path helper class.

Answer (score 61):

If this is happening to you on a **production environment** or with an app that you can't change, the quick fix is to empty the Temp folder.

Depending on the user that is running the application you should either

- Empty `C:\Windows\Temp` (for IIS or services running under `LocalSystem` account)
- Or `%temp%` for locally logged on users (which for me is `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp`).

On the other side, if your own code is throwing this, and you want to prevent this from happening ever again:

1. **Do not use System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()!**

`GetTempFileName()` is a wrapper of the [two decades old Win32 Api](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32GetTempFileName.htm). It generate file names that will very easily collide. It circumvents those collitions by heavily looping on the file system, iterating possible file names from `"%temp%\tmp0000.tmp"` to `"tmpFFFF.tmp"` and skipping already existing ones. This is a I/O intensive, slow, and frankly terrible algorithm. Also using only 4 hex characters is what makes the artificial limit of 65536 files before failing.

The alternative is to generate file names that will not collide. For example, lets reuse `GUID's` logic: 32 hex digits will almost never collide.

```
private string GetTempFileName()
{
    return Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
// Sample: c:\Windows\Temp\2e38fe87-f6bb-4b0d-90b3-2d07016324c1
```

This expands the limit from 65k to 4k millions files max (theoretically)... Of course, having leaked 65k files is already terrible, so...

2. **Do not leak temp files!**

Double check your app for all happy and unhappy paths (like unexpected exceptions). Ensure it's correctly disposing each FileStream and deleting the temp files in Finally blocks .

3. **Clean the temp folder**

Clean it now, and educate the system administrator to clean it periodically, because you can't trust every app in the wild.
On my own servers I would automate this task using:

- For global Windows\Temp

`schtasks /Create /TR "cmd /c call DEL /F /S /Q %^TEMP%" /TN "Delete Global Temp Files" /sc WEEKLY /ST 12:00 /ru system`

- For current user:

`schtasks /Create /TR "cmd /c call DEL /F /S /Q %^TEMP%" /TN "Delete %username% Temp Files" /sc WEEKLY /ST 12:00`

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code I used in the end, and put early in my app's initialization code-path, before any calls to `Cursor.LoadFromStream` might occur:

```
    private void WarnUserIfTempFolderFull()
    {
        string tempFile = null;
        try
        {
            tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            string problem = "The Temporary Folder is full.";

            string message = "{ProductName} has detected that the Windows Temporary Folder is full. \n" + 
                             "This may prevent the {ProductName} from functioning correctly.\n" + 
                             "Please delete old files in your temporary folder (%TEMP%) and try again.";

            Logger.Warn(problem);

            MessageBox.Show(message, caption: problem);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tempFile != null) File.Delete(tempFile);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// one more implementation
string GetTempFileName()
{
    return Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who has experienced this problem and can't find any overflowing temp-folder -
Check the "C:/Windows/Temp"-folder. Cleaning this folder solved my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions:

1. The right one. Detect which application is producing so many temporary files and not deleting them. Utilities like [`Process monitor`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) should help you. Then either fix the application or throw it away. And yes, this might be your application. that's why I'd recommend you to detect the source of evil.
2. The easiest one. Use your own temporary directory. This won't help if the files are being created from your code.
3. The ugliest one. Clear the temporary directory from your application. You're absolutely right about the consequences - you could break another application.

Comment: Using your own temp directory isn't necessarily a solution. I use the API to generate a tempfilename but write it to my own directory. Unfortunately even THAT fails.

Answer (score 1):

As [Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324033/sayse) suggested, you might try setting the %TEMP% environment variable when your app launches.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", "<dir>");
```

Comment: That's a great idea, but unfortunately my app is a Visual Studio extension which must peacefully co-exists with other extensions, and I'm afraid this might somehow inadvertently damage the behavior of the other extensions.

Comment: This solution will not help if it's his own program which is leaving behind all these files. The new directory will just fill up and it's bad to arbitrarily delete files from a folder when you have no idea what they are for even if it's a folder specific to your application.

Comment: @Ashigore Yes, obviously this won't fix a bug he has created. Specifically referencing `what if they are regularly running some other piece of software that makes frequent calls to GetTempFileName`.

Comment: @OmerRaviv This information is helpful. Indeed this won't work in this scenario.

Comment: A program should not change the system without user knowledge. Find another solution that only affects your application.

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli Downvote? This changes only the running process. Not the system.

Comment: I take the downvote back as the OP is talking about a WPF app. Still, if you do this on a console application, the change affects the whole console host until it's closed.

Comment: Sorry @EdChapel, SO has locked my vote, I can't remove it unless the answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Set the file attribute to temporary explicitly, and make sure you delete the file after use.

```
 File.SetAttributes(tempFileName, FileAttributes.Temporary);
```