# VS2013 crashing when I go to Team Explorer and click on 'Changes'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

my VS2013 installation never had any crashes but this week it started showing this error at startup:

```
An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension. You can get more information by bexamining the file (...)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml
```

Then it opens correctly and I can work normally. However, when I try to commit my local changes and open the Team Explorer and click on CHanges, Visual Studio crashes.

I looked into the ActivityLog.xml and fount this error:

```
<entry>
<record>179</record>
<time>2015/02/27 17:51:35.065</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
<description>System.IO.IOException: The file exists.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.WpfHelper.LoadCursorDPIAware(Stream cursorStream)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.LeftSelectionMargin.get_RightArrowCursor()&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.LeftSelectionMarginProvider.CreateMargin(IWpfTextViewHost textViewHost, IWpfTextViewMargin containerMargin)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.ContainerMargin.&lt;AddMargins&gt;b__2(IWpfTextViewMarginProvider mp)&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InstantiateExtension[TExtension,TMetadata,TExtensionInstance](Object errorSource, Lazy`2 provider, Func`2 getter)</description>

</entry>
```

I tried deleting all my projects, cloning them again and this persists.
Can anyone help me figuring this out?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found out what was going on. This happens because my Windows Temp folder has more than 65535 files. Had to clean out my Temp folder (---\User\AppData\Local\Temp)

Found at:

[System.IO.IOException: "The file exists" when using System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() - resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350699/system-io-ioexception-the-file-exists-when-using-system-io-path-gettempfilena)

I think this is not a duplicated problem. This targets VS2013 specifically.

Comment: Exactly resolved my VS2013 issue as well.  Thanks!  Just ran a Disk Cleanup and including deleting of temporary files

Answer (score 1):

try

```
devenv.exe /setup
```

It helps me in similar cases