# Optimize Linq Contains method

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I need a list from OldGuids that are not in the NewGuids, so I used the Contains method, the problem is that it is already running more then half hour, is there a faster way? or how much longer would it take about?

```
Dim OldGuids As New List(Of Guid) ' 18 million rows
Dim NewGuids As New List(Of Guid) ' 6 million rows
Dim Filtered = From n In OldGuids Where Not NewGuids.Contains(n)
```

Comment: April 1st?  It is taken: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705008/simple-proof-that-guid-is-not-unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Filtered = OldGuids.Except(NewGuids)
```

(Note that this will only return unique elements, if you want to preserve duplicates this is not what you want).

---

```
var newGuidSet=new HashSet<Guid>(newGuids);
Filtered = OldGuids.Where(g=>!newGuidSet.Contains(g));
```

Comment: will it be much faster then contains?

Comment: It will be fast, but take about 400MB or RAM.

Comment: I get system out of memory exception, there is plenty of space on the hard drive

Comment: I've added a second solution which requires a bit less memory. If that isn't enough, switch to 64bit and download more RAM.

Comment: Making `NewGuids` a `HashSet` is enough for your specific use, and saves a bit of memory.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `HashSet<Guid>`s.

You can then write `OldGuids.IntersectWith(NewGuids)`

Comment: `IntersectWith` doesn't help here. You missed a `not` in the question.

Comment: The method that should be used is `ExceptWith`, not `IntersectWith`