# Is the following acceptable foreign key usage

Tags: sql, database-design

I have the following database, the first table users is a table containing my users, userid is a primary key.

[image: user table]

The next is my results table, now for each user, there can be a result with an id and it can be against an exam.  Is it ok in this scenario to use "id" as a primary key and "userid" as a foreign key?  Is there a better way I could model this scenario?

[image: results table]

These then link to the corresponding exams...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably not have `userid` as a `varchar`. I would have that as an `int` as well.

So the user table is like this:

```
userId int
userName varchar
firstName varchar
lastName varchar
```

And then the forenkey in the results table table would be an `int`. Like this:

```
userId int
result varchar
id int
examid INT
```

Becuase if you are plaing on `JOIN` ing the tables together then `JOIN` ing on a `varchar` is not as fast as `JOIN` ing on a `INT`

**EDIT**

That depend on how much data you are planing to store. Beause you know that there is a minimum chans that `GUID`s are not unique. [Simple proof that GUID is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705008/simple-proof-that-guid-is-not-unique). I think if I would design this database I would go with an int. Becuase it feels a little bit overkill to use a `GUID` as a userid

Comment: I was actually considering using a GUID for the primary key of the user, rather than an int.  Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @david99world : Remember to up vote the answers you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P

Answer (score 1):

Provided that each user/exam will only ever produce one result, then you could create a composite key using the `userid` and `exam` columns in the results table.

Personally though, i'd go with the arbitrary `id` field approach as I don't like having to pass in several values to reference records. But that's just me :).

Also, the `exam` field in the results table should also be a foreign key.

Comment: I'd also recommend renaming the exam foreign key field in the results table to 'examid' to keep the naming consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this could be to abstract the Grade Levels from the Exam, and make the Exam a unique entity (and primary key) on its own table. So this would make a Grade Levels table (pkey1 = A, pkey2 = B, etc) where the grade acts as the foreign key in your second table, thus removing an entire field.

You could also normal out another level and make a table for Subjects, which would be the foreign key for a dedicated Exam Code table. You can have ENG101, ENG102, etc for exams, and the same for the other exam codes for the subject. The benefit of this is to maintain your exams, subjects, students and grade levels as unique entities. The primary and foreign keys of each are evident, and you keep a simple maintenance future with room to scale up.

You could consider using composite keys, but this is a nice and simple way to start, and you can merge tables for indexing and compacting as required.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you first understand [Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) before actually normalizing your schema.

Comment: Ah ok, so I should split out the values in my result table into seperate tables to have first normal form.