# Is Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId multi-processor safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Will `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` return the unique Id on the multiprocessor machine.

Explanation: I want to generate unique number. i generated unique number based on current time i.e. 
currentTmeinmillisecons but two threads access the same function in same timestamp  so i want to  add something unique in that timestamp. So planning to  to add `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`  in CurrentTimeInMilliseconds.

So can I add Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId  in CurrentTimeInMilliseconds.

Comment: Please learn formatting your question..

Comment: Sorry for the wrong formmating, I corrected the same.

Comment: If it doesnt need to be a number use `Guid`

Comment: GUID is not unique as i seen in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705008/simple-proof-that-guid-is-not-unique"

Comment: @SaurabhMahajan - Do you actually understand the answers to that question? GUID is "unique" to an extent that many other events (such as the extinction of life on Earth) are far more likely to occur before you get an accidental collision.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` will return a unique id at a given instant in time. But as one thread quits and another one starts the new one might get the old `Id`. Your premise is flawed.

Comment: @ta.speot.is reference? It seems obvious that this would be the case (that the thread ID would only be unique among active threads until the thread exits), but I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: The documentation says "unique identifier" but gives no further guarantee. So it's unique for an instant of time. http://rocksolid.gibraltarsoftware.com/development/logging/managed-thread-ids-unique-ids-that-arent-unique

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you mean by "add Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId in CurrentTimeInMilliseconds". Say, for ManagedThreadId+CurrentTimeInMilliseconds:

```
1+2 = 3
2+1 = 3
```

So are you actually creating a "unique" value in the end? What happens if you call it more than once per millisecond? If you need something that will be unique per-process per-call, I'd do something like:

```
using System.Threading;

static class Foo
{
    static long i;
    public static long GetUnique() { return Interlocked.Increment(ref i); }
}
```

If you want to generate a unique number over multiple processes, `Guid` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur reply.But actually my method that will return get time in milliseconds was working fine but i faced a issue on multiprocessor machine because , method is called from two threads and both the threads got same timestamp. I want to provide different - different timestamp to  all the threads .

Comment: *I want to provide different - different timestamp to all the threads* Then call the method at different times. Otherwise what you're given to all the threads is not a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for the great reply.
Actually my method works fine. but i want to update my method only.
so how can i generate unique number on multiprocessor machine.
So i am doing 
  
  
  return  currenttimeinMilliseconds  +   Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId  //unique number 
  
  So question is : So it will work fine or not on multiprocessor machine.
  It already works fine in single processor mchine.

  Actually i am asking for multiprocessor becasuse if  Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId   is different for different different threads then my function will return unique number.

Comment: I can't sufficiently understand you. If you update your question with code, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: @CoryNelson `Guid` is not a good choice to create unique number, had tested it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time/21570510#21570510