# F# WPF set custom assembly title

Tags: wpf, f#

I'm designing a consumer application using F# WPF and I noticed that there is no equivalent of AssemblyInfo.cs in C# projects where I can usually define custom assembly title. Without it my F# app is shown in the Task Manager as `MyApp.exe` while I want it to be shown as just `MyApp`.

[This blog post](http://mike-ward.net/2012/05/26/learning-fndashassembly-level-attributes) recommends creating AssemblyInfo.fs manually. I tried this:

```
module AssemblyInfo

open System  
open System.Reflection;  
open System.Runtime.InteropServices;  

[<assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyApp")>]
do()
```

however it doesn't seem to work.

How do I set custom assembly title in an F# application?

Comment: How exactly does it "not seem to work"?

Comment: What IDE or editor are you using? With VS 2015 Community it is created automatically when I start a new F# console project.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin assembly title still missing in file details of the .exe and Task Manager still shows `MyApp.exe`.

Comment: @GuyCoder I'm using VS2013 Pro Update 5.

Comment: Have you tried specifying all attributes that you had in your previous C# apps exactly as they were there?

Comment: No, I haven't. I tried to assign only AssemblyTitle. Don't see how it can be dependent on any other assembly attribute. To make it clear -- I'm not porting an existing C# app to F#. It's a new app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated this, and discovered that AssemblyTitle on its own is not sufficient. The title will then not appear in Task Manager, as you found out. You need to supply with more attributes in order to make this attribute work, but I don't know which ones makes the difference.

This is a file from a project of mine originally created in VS2015. If you use it in VS2013, remember to generate a new GUID for each assembly where you use it. You can do that somewhere in the main menu of VS. Or you can buy 
[quality GUIDs made in China](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705008/simple-proof-that-guid-is-not-unique).

AssemblyInfo.fs

```
namespace SecondDemo.AssemblyInfo

open System.Reflection
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[<assembly: AssemblyTitle("SecondDemo")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyDescription("")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyCompany("")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyProduct("SecondDemo")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2017")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyCulture("")>]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[<assembly: ComVisible(false)>]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[<assembly: Guid("827700cd-54f6-4485-9239-fbd6af43c3e5")>]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
// 
//       Major Version
//       Minor Version 
//       Build Number
//       Revision
// 
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [<assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>]

do ()
```