# Will NEWID() in T-SQL and System.Guid.NewGuid() create the same key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, guid, uniqueidentifier

I know that if you use `NEWID()` in SQL itself will not create repeated keys.

And the same goes for `NewGuid()` within C# environment.

But how about do it on both side?

Such as create a `NewGuid()` and insert it into SQL Server table in part of the code and call `NEWID()` in another part of the code.

Will they create the same key, no matter how unlikely it is, and cause trouble!?

Much appreciated!

Comment: `NEWID` and `NewGuid()` will generate a new value every time they are called. The chances of either creating the same value in separate calls is so small that it might as well be impossible.

Comment: So it's "possible"!? @.@

Comment: @PiggyChu001: here is more information on GUID collision (duplication): https://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/11/few-words-on-guids.html#:~:text=Assuming%20a%20perfect%20source%20of,That's%20a%20lot.

Comment: @PiggyChu001 the probability is around the same as `Guid.NewGuid()` [will generate duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1705604/2501279).

Comment: OK! I guess the answer is "It's possible but the chance is so astronomically small that it would be idiotic of me to worry about it"! Thanks for y'all! ^O^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) writes: UUIDs are for practical purposes unique.

It doesn't matter if it is generated by two different methods.