# How's GUID determined?

Tags: com, guid

How can applications ensure it's unique?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a GUID unique 100% of the time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a 128-bit number - collisions are pretty unlikely.  Even if it were completely random, you'd be unlikely to get a duplicate even in the history of the universe.  There are some modifications to pure randomness to help even those collisions from occuring in practice - you can read several of them on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier).

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is your friend:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: Actually, I don't think they can collide, on the same machine, unless you somehow freeze the clock and generate GUIDs looking for a collision.

Comment: @Kyle: I did. What's the problem?

Comment: 1. They're not unique, just highly unlikely to be regenerated. 2. They do not use machine specific data with the current time anymore, they use PRNGs. The only thing right in your answer, is the link.

Comment: Hmm, you are correct (although, only according to the UUID page, as posted by Carl). I've amended my answer to just include the link, then.