# How to generate a Uniq Number C#

Tags: c#

I want to generate a Uniq Number something like TMP-0001354, TMP will be always same only number will get change, which should not be get duplicate in table.

I want to a exp. code which should be in c#, I'll call that function at the time of inserting the record in table. SQL server database I am using

I am trying this I don't know will it work fine or not.

```
 private string RandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        int maxSize = 8;
        int minSize = 5;
        char[] chars = new char[62];
        string a;
        a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        chars = a.ToCharArray();
        int size = maxSize;
        byte[] data = new byte[1];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
        size = maxSize;
        data = new byte[size];
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(size);
        foreach (byte b in data)
        { result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length - 1)]); }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Some one please help me.

Comment: Table? Database Table? DataTable for C#? What kind of table are you talking about?

Comment: Use DateTime.Now.Ticks()

Comment: Take a look at the HiLo key algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generate uniq number use this (the number can start with 0):

```
string number_s = "TMP-" + RandomNumber(0, 9) + RandomNumber(0, 9) + RandomNumber(0, 9) + RandomNumber(0, 9) + RandomNumber(0, 9) + RandomNumber(0, 9) + RandomNumber(0, 9);
```

or this (is shorter, but will begin with 1):

```
string number_s = "TMP-" + RandomNumber(1000000, 9999999);
```

This is the code for `RandomNumber`:

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
        private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
        public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            { // synchronize
                return random.Next(min, max);
            }
        }
```

It works nice for me. Hope that I helped you.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

This generates a unique number. append the constant part to this guid.

Comment: 'TMP-' is just a constant prefix. If we add that prefix to a unique number the compound is unique. The question's main concern is avoiding duplicates rather than a rigid format. the identifier has 2 parts "TMP-" part and "unique number" part. That is how i perceived the question? If the unique number part is rigid w.r.t the number of digits then i do agree with you that GUID's format wont work here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mini hash, guid, you could also use the time year month day seconds miliseconds, or a timestamp.

there are many ways to make a unique ID

Answer (score 0):

You might try [System.Guid.NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which generates a [global unique identifier (GUID)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).

Answer (score 0):

```
return string.Format("TMP-{0:d}", DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

also see this SO post:

- [How to Generate Unique Number in C# of 8 digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103610/how-to-generate-unique-number-in-c-sharp-of-8-digits)