# How to generate Serial No with sequence for barcode C# insert IN datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I'm new in this world I want to generate serial no like `000001` to `000010` from user input when I click generate btn generate no in insert to `datagridview` and when I click save btn then save this `datagridview` data in table like 
`id`,`barcodeNO`,`ColorName`,`size`

```
+---+----------+--------+------+
| 1 |  000001  |  pink  |  39  |
+---+----------+--------+------+
| 2 |  000002  |  pink  |  40  |
+---+----------+--------+------+
| 3 |  000003  |  pink  |  41  |
+---+----------+--------+------+
```

I'm successful to generate range from user input with color and size now problem in  generate only serial no.

Here is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); a < int.Parse(textBox2.Text);           a = a + 1)
    {
        int row = 0;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count -2;
        dataGridView1["color", row].Value = textBox3.Text;
        dataGridView1["Size", row].Value = a;
        //[enter image description here][1]dataGridView1["Barcode", row].Value = dt.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
dataGridView1["Barcode", row].Value = a.ToString("000000");
```

see [custom numeric formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i barcode number is not repeat again with size i need unique no like when i generate one item barcode have color size

Comment: thanks for your answer but i barcode number is not repeat again with size i need unique no like when i generate one item barcode have color size like 
color Size barcode 
pink   39    00005
pink   40    00006
after save not repaet this number again 
like 
red      39 00007
red      40 00008
blue     40 00009

Comment: take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103610/how-to-generate-unique-number-of-8-digits). Also, you should keep generated barcodes somewhere to be sure there's no duplicates...