# Entity Framework and SQL CE GUID as PK's

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a GUID unique 100% of the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time)

I'm using GUID as my primary key columns for tables in a SQL CE 3.5 database that I'm performing CRUD operations on using Entity Framework.

When I create my id's I set them as

```
configuration.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

How unique is `Guid`? It's a pretty big string, is there any possibility that `Guid.NewGuid()` could return a value that it already used?

Comment: The answer is no, but effectively yes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time

Answer (score 2):

It is technically *possible*, but [so unlikely that you don't have to worry about it](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/11/few-words-on-guids.html).

Note that `Guid.NewGuid` is not kind to database index clustering. I did design a [combed GUID for use on mobile devices](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/08/alternative-guids-for-mobile-devices.html) back in the day if that helps.