# How to check if random values are unique?

Tags: c#, arrays, random, numbers

C # code:

I have 20 random numbers between 1-100 in an array and the program should check if every value is unique. Now i should use another method which returns true if there are only unique values in the array and false if there are not any unique values in the array. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Hint: look at `Distinct()`

Comment: Count the elements of your array, then count the distinct elements of your array and compare both values. You can do this with Linq.

Comment: @GrantWinney: that's not relevant. Using *Linq*, it will use the `Equals` method which can be overriden.

Comment: Do your own homework or you will not learn anything!

Comment: @GrantWinney: you most certainly can. An array `T[]` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`... You only need write `using System.Linq`.

Answer (score 8):

```
bool allUnique = array.Distinct().Count() == array.Count(); // or array.Length
```

or

```
var uniqueNumbers = new HashSet<int>(array);
bool allUnique = uniqueNumbers.Count == array.Count();
```

Answer (score 5):

A small alternative to @TimSchmelters excellent answers that can run a bit more efficient:

```
public static bool AllUniq<T> (this IEnumerable<T> data) {
    HashSet<T> hs = new HashSet<T>();
    return data.All(hs.Add);
}
```

What this basically does is generating a `for` loop:

```
public static bool AllUniq<T> (this IEnumerable<T> data) {
    HashSet<T> hs = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach(T x in data) {
        if(!hs.Add(x)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

From the moment one [`hs.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) fails - this because the element already exists - the method returns `false`, if no such object can be found, it returns `true`.

The reason that this can work faster is that it will stop the process from the moment a duplicate is found whereas the previously discussed approaches first construct a collection of unique numbers and then compare the size. Now if you iterate over large amount of numbers, constructing the entire distinct list can be computationally intensive.

Furthermore note that there are more clever ways than *generate-and-test* to [generate random distinct numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473321/generating-random-unique-values-c-sharp). For instance interleave the *generate* and *test* procedure. Once a project I had to correct generated Sudoku's this way. The result was that one had to wait entire days before it came up with a puzzle.

Comment: ++: i even prefer this over mine

Comment: Tim's method could be slightly faster if `data` implments `ICollection<T>`, the constructor that takes in a `IEnumerable` [has some optimizations](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/d0822f25708256c5.html) to pre-size it's internal storage if the source enumerable implements `ICollection<T>`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: in case there are no duplicates, yes. In case there are duplicates (on average [87%](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-100!%2F%28%28100-n%29!*100^n%29+with+n%3D20) of the cases it will probably be a bit faster. The optimization lies in breaking of the processing immediately. But in case there are no duplicates, it can indeed result in a *O(log n)* overhead for reorganizing the `HashSet<T>` now and then.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non linq solution

```
  for(int i=0; i< YourArray.Length;i++)
  {
    for(int x=i+1;  x< YourArray.Length; x++)
    {
      if(YourArray[i] == YourArray[x])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found repeated value");
        }
    }   
  }
```

Comment: This works but is less efficient since it scales quadratic in time whereas a `HashSet`-approach like `Distinct()` have an average time complexity of *O(n)* and (depending on the implementation of the `HashSet`) sometimes a guaranteed complexity of *O(n log n)*

Comment: Something tells me that this is for homework. @CommuSoft

Comment: You could/should still use a hashset and save a ton of time, you could still make it "Non Linq" by replacing your inner `for` loop with `if(hs.Add(YourArray[i])`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain if you post that as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: No, I wont. That answer would just be expanding the LINQ in CommuSoft's answer to be a for loop without adding any value.