# c# unique random number

Tags: c#, random, numbers

i'm trying to get X number of random number (where X is a variable) between 0 and 100 and add them to a row in a DataGridView. I'm using the code below, but the problem is i need it to be impossible to have the same number twice. Is there a way make sure i get unique random numbers?

```
int X = 20;
Random random = new Random();
int randomrow = random.Next(0, 100);

for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
   int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
   data.Rows[randomrow][3] = randomNumber;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use a List<int> to hold your random values. when you generate a new one check if it exists in that list and generate a new one if it does, then add them all to the DataGridView

Comment: Do you want `randomrow` to be unique? Or `randomNumber`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random, unique values C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473321/generating-random-unique-values-c-sharp)

Comment: If you want a true random value, you need to use something other than the `Random` class. [`Random` is only psuedo-random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness). In order to generate real ones, you can use something like `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

Comment: Why does randomrow never change? You are updating the same row x times.

Comment: What happens if x is 101?

Comment: Note that the second argument to [`Random.Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) is the *exclusive* upper bound.  `Random.Next(0, 100)` returns a random integer between 0 and 99, and will never return 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the simple way to do it without creating a shuffle method for the List (though there are examples of that). Basically create a list of all possible integers, populate the list, then sort by new GUIDs.

```
        int X = 20;
        var RowNumbers = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
            RowNumbers.Add(i);

        foreach (int i in RowNumbers.OrderBy(f => Guid.NewGuid()))
        {
            data.Rows[i][3] = i;
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Split your problem in two:

1. Create a list of X random, unique numbers. There are numerous ways to do that:

   a. Create a list of all numbers 0-100 and then [shuffle them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273313/87698). OR

   b. Keep a hash set of all the numbers you already created (in addition to the list) and only add a new one if it has not been added before.
2. Afterwards, loop through the list and the data rows simultaneously and insert the values into the rows.

Comment: The list should be a [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MatiasCicero: I don't think so: A hashset has no defined order, so shuffling is not possible.

Comment: Making a list of 0 to 100 won't have duplicates either, and then shuffling is O(n) basically. This is a lot better than generating random unique numbers, redoing all the ones that already existed, while having more and more already existing numbers as you go.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Oh I understand now, my bad!

Comment: @MatiasCicero: But your suggestion of using a hash set is good *if* the OP sticks to his original algorithm. I've added that option.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to compare the numbers you have already used to the next one you get from random.Next.  If you have already used it, pick another.  I also like Heinzi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is algorithm without shuffling and previous result using:

```
var max = 100; // max available value
var count = 20; // number of random numbers

var random = new Random();
var rest = (double)max;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++, rest--)
{
    if (count / rest > random.NextDouble())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i); // here is your random value
        count--;

        if (count == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```