# How to select random items from ListBox without repeating

Tags: c#, random, listbox

I'm creating another random generator from `ListBox`. I want them to randomly pick 3 items from `listBox` and then display it on `TextBox`.

```
Random random = new Random();
int a = random.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count);
listBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items[a];
int b = random.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count);
listBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items[b];
int c = random.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count);
listBox1.SelectedItem = listBox1.Items[c];
listBox1.Select();
textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items[a] + ", " + listBox1.Items[b] + ", " + listBox1.Items[c];
```

The issue is sometimes the items are selected twice.
Example:

listBox items: One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six

Output: One, Six, One (the item 'One' is selected twice, which I don't want to)

Thanks.

Comment: Use enumerable.range to get a list of integers from 0 to list.count - 1. Look up a shuffling algorithm.  Like shuffling a deck of cards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random, unique values C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473321/generating-random-unique-values-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your logic like this:

1. Get 3 random numbers
2. Select the values from the `ListBox`

Code could look like. This code will get a new random number when the current was already selected and stores it in a `List<int>`.

```
Random random = new Random();
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int number = random.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count);
    while (numbers.Contains(number))
    {
        number = random.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count);
    }
    numbers.Add(number);
}
```

and then

```
textBox1.Text = $"{listBox1.Items[numbers[0]]}, {listBox1.Items[numbers[1]]}, {listBox1.Items[numbers[2]]}";
```

If you have less then 3 items in your `ListBox` this will end in an infinity loop, be aware of this.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what's `$` for in the `textBox1.Text`?

Comment: @Alfian `String interpolation` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings thats so you can add variables in the text like this `$"this is text this is {variableName}"`

Comment: @Alfian Short form for [string.format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) Your welcome and when it's working please accept the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, all. and thanks @MightyBadaboom for the answer and it works. You might edit your post by removing `(` on `textBox1.Text` as it was make me confused before.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a while loop and only exit when they don't match:

```
Random random = new Random();
int listBoxItemCount = listBox1.Items.Count;
var itemA = listBox1.Items[random.Next( listBoxItemCount )];
var itemB = listBox1.Items[random.Next( listBoxItemCount )];
var itemC = listBox1.Items[random.Next( listBoxItemCount )];

while(itemA == itemB || itemA == itemC || itemB == itemC)//While any pair matches
{ 
    itemB = listBox1.Items[ random.Next( listBoxItemCount ) ];
    itemC = listBox1.Items[ random.Next( listBoxItemCount ) ];
}
```

This will result in a unique `itemA`, `itemB` and `itemC`

Comment: @Downvote explain please so I can improve my post. This solution does work

Comment: I'm not the one who downvote it, I can't even upvote since I'm still new user. by the way, thanks for answering and it works. I will use this as temporarily workaround, as there will be a better answers, maybe.

Comment: @Alfian I already saw you couldn't downvote :) and I don't really mind the vote itself its just that I can't improve my post without feedback and losing progress towards silver c# badge -_-

Answer (score 0):

See: [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

I modified and made a .net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a7RJbm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = Enumerable.Range( 0, 6 ).ToList();
        list.Shuffle();
        int a = list[0];
        int b = list[1];
        int c = list[2];
        Console.WriteLine( a );
        Console.WriteLine( b );
        Console.WriteLine( c );
    }       

}

public static class ListShuffler
{
    private static Random rng = new Random();
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            T value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The benefit of shuffling is that you can go randomly through all of the items in the list.  If you wanted to do more than 3 items some other approaches start to get a bit ugly.