# How to avoid repeat random number, I want to generate random number in asp.net in billions but its repeating

Tags: c#

```
static Random r = new Random();

public static int Randfunc(int start, int end)
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    int n = r.Next(start, end);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: You do nothing to keep track of the numbers you already generated, at least not in this code.

Comment: You want to avoid repeating last number twice or store each number once?

Comment: Why would it be prohibited to generate the same number multiple times randomly? It might also give you 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random, unique values C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473321/generating-random-unique-values-c-sharp)

Comment: Yeah, if you ban repeating numbers, then it's not random any more.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [shuffled list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like that;

```
        var start = 0;//Min range of numbers
        var end = 1000;//Max range of numbers
        int i = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        var numbers = new HashSet<int>();
        while(i < 100)//Collect 100 unique numbers
        {
            var number = random.Next(start, end);
            if (!numbers.Contains(number))
            {
                numbers.Add(number);
                i++;
            }
        }
```