# random numbers only once in an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I want to generate random numbers and put them in an array, but they should only appear once in this array. It's like a mini lotto game.
This is the code I have right now:

```
int[] arrA = new int[10];
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i <= arrA.Length -1; i++)
{           
    arrA[i] = random.Next(1, 15);
    Console.WriteLine(arrA[i]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Random numbers are generated and put in this Array. I only need to know how it's possible to program that they only appeare once.

Comment: When you pick a random number, check whether it's already in the array. If it is, pick another one.

Comment: But how can I do that?

Comment: `.Contains(...)`?

Comment: Requiring only one number isn't *random*, especially when the range is so small. When you place the uniquness constraint you end up with far more predictable numbers

Comment: a one-liner to do what you want is: var arrA = Enumerable.Range(1,14).OrderBy(g => random.Next()).Take(10).ToArray();    (The idea for this comes https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716618/1633949)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  int[] arrA = new int[10];
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i <= arrA.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        var number = random.Next(1, 15);
        while (arrA.Any(n => n == number))
        {
            number = random.Next(1, 15);
        }

        arrA[i] = number;
        Console.WriteLine(arrA[i]);
    }


    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But could you may explain to me how this 'while' works?

Comment: while (arrA.Any(n => n == number)) means that if the generated random number exists in the array generate an other and so on, its a loop that finish only if the random number does't exist in the array. take a look on Microsoft documentation for more information and exemple

Comment: Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while

Answer (score 1):

Use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.

Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Start with a random number
    //
    int value = random.Next(1,15);

    // Check whether you already have that number
    // Keep trying until you get a unique
    //
    while (numbers.Contains(value)) {
        value = random.Next(1,15);
    }

    // Add the unique number to the set
    numbers.Add(value);
}
foreach (int i in numbers)
{
    Console.Write(" {0}", i);
}
```

Comment: You could add a while loop to ensure `numbers` always has 10 unique random values.

Comment: the hashset will not containt the 10 elements if the generated number exists already.
the count = 10 - duplicated numbers

Comment: Ah, right, thanks. I thought the same thing as soon as I posted.  Edited to add the check.

Comment: You can simplify your code by using a return value from [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#returns). Something like `for (var i=0;i<10;++i) while (!numbers.Add(random.Next(1, 15)));`

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you generate a new number, instead of putting it in the array right away check the array from the start to the current position (using a for-loop). If it's not there insert the generated number, otherwise generate a new one and repeat the process.