# Generate a unique random number between 1 and 10?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to generate a unique random digit between 1 and 10. If a number gets repeated then the script should skip the number and try for another. If there are no unique numbers left then a message should be generated. Any logic to get this concept implemented?

```
public int number; 

    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
          number= Random.Range(1,10);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: It is not a duplicate of the link the user posted since I am trying to generate unique number and if a particular number is repeated, the script ignores it and tries to look for another number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Comment: A shuffle would be more logical.

Comment: Create a collection of `1..10` values, *shuffle* it, then take `1st, 2nd, ..., 10th` item from it when all items are taken generate the message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random, unique values C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473321/generating-random-unique-values-c-sharp)

Comment: Probably not a duplicate. Very very similar, but Unity Random acts differently than System Random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Setup a list with all the valid values at Awake
2. Get a random value from the list
3. Remove the value from the list to avoid duplicates
4. BONUS - You could also extend the class to set any min and max numbers

```cs
public class RandomGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int minNumber = 1;
    public int maxNumber = 10;

    private List<int> _validNumbers;

    public int number;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _validNumbers = new List<int>();
        for (int i = minNumber; i <= maxNumber; i++)
            _validNumbers.Add(i);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            if (_validNumbers.Count == 0)
                Debug.Log("No valid Numbers");
            else
                number = GetRandomNumber();
        }
    }

    private int GetRandomNumber()
    {
        var nextIndex = Random.Range(0, _validNumbers.Count - 1);
        var result    = _validNumbers[nextIndex];
        _validNumbers.RemoveAt(nextIndex);
        return result;
    }
}
```

EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:
This question is very similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473321/generating-random-unique-values-c-sharp). But [Unity.Random](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html) is different than [System.Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8).

The answers offered in the other question work here too. But we have more choices here.

Comment: Works like charm!

Comment: Seems like you linked the "this other question" to this one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just updated the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473321/generating-random-unique-values-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

As guys suggested in the comments, shuffling might work:

```
public class Shuffler
{
    private readonly Queue<int> _queue;

    public Shuffler(int max)
    {           
        _queue = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, max).OrderBy(x => UnityEngine.Random.value));
    }

    public bool TryGetNext(out int item)
    {
        if(_queue.Count == 0)
        {
            item = -1;
            return false;
        }

        item = _queue.Dequeue();
        return true;
    }
}
```

For the sake of completenes, adding `MonoBehaviour`, e.g.

```
public class RandomNumber : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Shuffler _shuffler;

    public int number;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _shuffler = new Shuffler(10)
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            if(!_shuffler.TryGetNext(out number))
            {
                Debug.Log("No valid Numbers");
            }
        }
    }
}
```