# How can I achieve following using MVC scaffolding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have an SQL Server 2008 database.
All tables having a GUID as the primary key, and they are NOT auto-generated. Rather, I want my code to generate it and pass it in INSERT operation.
Some of the tables are having one-to-one or one-to-many relations with other tables.

Is it easy to implement having CRUD operations for such kind of database, where the end-user will not need to worry about GUIDs and all? I searched for tutorials for this, but couldn't find. Can anyone guide me in right direction?

I have MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I gotta ask why all your primary keys are GUIDs and not something more...normal like integers - something that can be efficiently indexed, etc.  Why?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Guid is always unique.

Comment: @Garath May be not always...

Comment: There are many advantages of having GUID as primary key, and they are unique as far as I know (i've read many blogs for this, and they all reckon its unique!).

Comment: @BhushanFirake Not exactly always but probability of same guid is almost zero look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time