# LINQ GroupBy() only if true

Tags: c#

I need to group data using a custom condition, which returns `true` or `false`. The complexity is, I need to group only the items which return `true` and do not group the others.

If I use:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(d => new { Condition = d.SomeValue > 1 });
```

all the items get grouped by `true`/`false`.

Now I have this statement that works:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(d => new { Condition = d.SomeValue > 1 ? "true" : FunctionToGetUniqueString() });
```

**UPDATE:** Note, the other items (which are `false`) must also be in the grouping, but go separately (one per group).

But I think it is a bit dirty solution, so I though that maybe there is something more elegant?

Comment: I think your solution works; I would just be sure to add detailed comments to explain what the expected result is.

Comment: This isn't a grouping query. This is a simple `Where` filter. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution works; I would just be sure to add detailed comments to explain what the expected result is.

If you want to use a "built-in" string generator rather than creating your own you could use `Guid.NewGuid()`:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(d => new { Condition = d.SomeValue > 1 
                                     ? "true"
                                     : Guid.NewGuid().ToString() })
```

Also you don't need an anonymous type unless you want to *use* the `Condition` value later:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(d => d.SomeValue > 1 
                               ? Guid.Empty 
                               : Guid.NewGuid() )
```

Comment: I think `Guid.NewGuid()` is a good idea, but then I'd suggest to use `Guid.Empty` instead of `"_true"` as key for the items that don't match the condition

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `Guid.NewGuid()` will always return a unique string?

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid()` will return a `Guid`, not a `string`. And yes, it should always return a unique value

Comment: @net_prog GUID stands for Globally Unique IDentifier, so yes it is virtually[*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time) guaranteed to be unique

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be something like this:

```
var result = data
    .GroupBy(d => d.SomeValue > 1 ? 0 : d.ID);
```

Assuming `ID` is an `int` property that is unique among the items in your collection. Of course can adapt this technique pretty easily to work with if you've got a unique string property, etc. If you have no unique property, you can always do something like this:

```
var result = data
    .Select((d, i) => new { d, i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.d.SomeValue > 1 ? -1 : x.i, x => x.d);
```

This will work in Linq-to-Objects, but I'm not sure about other Linq providers (e.g. Linq-to-SQL, Linq-to-Entities). For those cases, *D Stanley*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18380735/1715579) might be the only way to go, but for simple Linq queries, this would be more efficient than generating a random `Guid` for every non-grouped item.

Of course, if this seems inelegant, you could always wrap it in an extension method. Note that I return an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` rather than `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, T>>`,  since the key really is not relevant here anyway:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhere<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> set,
    Func<T, bool> grouping)
{
    return set
        .Select((d, i) => new { d, i })
        .GroupBy(x => grouping(x.d) ? -1 : x.i, x => x.d);
}
```

Or this, which, which is has slightly different semantics (grouped items always appear last) but should be bit more efficient:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhere<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> set,
    Func<T, bool> grouping)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    foreach(var x in set)
    {
        if (!grouping(x))
        {
            yield return new[] { x };
        }
        else 
        {
            list.Add(x);
        }
    }

    yield return list;
}
```

Either way you can use this just like this:

```
var result = data.GroupWhere(d => d.SomeValue > 1);
```

Comment: The OP still _wants_ the results that do not match the condition; just not _grouped_