# Add random string in a column to each row in database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, random, passwords

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I got a database with around 1000 rows.

There is also a column called `Password`, which is empty for each row.

Normally I could do something like `INSERT INTO Password VALUES("helloworld");` to add something into the `Password` column, but then all rows will get the same `Password`.

But I want to have a different `Password` for every single row in the database, a random word with 10 characters (strings and integers).

Can someone guide me to the right path how I can do this?

Comment: Can you show the table definition?

Answer (score 3):

Using a substring of a guid may work :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(40), newid()), 1, 10)
```

If the dash is a problem, replace it.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(40), newid()), '-', ''), 1, 10)
```

However, note that this does not guarantee a unique password for every row, since we are only using a part of a guid.

Comment: And if I set the ''Password'' entity to unique in the database?

Comment: Is the password limited to 10 characters ? Or can we get 32 characters ? If we can use 32 characters, then replacing the dashes will give you a unique value. With dashes, you will need 36 characters.

Comment: No I could change to more then 10 characters, but I don't want to have long passwords :)

Comment: With 1000 passwords or even 10000, the method above is (highly) unlikely to produce a duplicate, but as mentioned it is not guaranteed.

Comment: For discussion about unique identifiers, I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time) question.