# why SYS_GUID() gives two different records when used in inner query?

Tags: oracle, guid

Below query gives two different IDs when run in Oracle.

```
SELECT B.ID AS ID1, B.ID AS ID2 FROM 
(SELECT SYS_GUID() AS ID FROM DUAL) B
```

Query gives different values for ID1 and ID2. We can have same value for ID1 and ID2 using `where ronum=1`, but why it gives two different IDs in above case?

Comment: not dup but similar .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time