# How to insert a uuid with the PHP-DB-Framework Eloquent？

Tags: eloquent

Environment：PHP, MariaDB, Eloquent

I can insert a uuid into a table easily, with sql query:

```
INSERT INTO `customer_loginToken` (`customer_id`, `loginToken`, `loginIP`) VALUES (1, uuid(), '127.0.0.1')
```

But how can I insert a uuid for the column 'loginToken' with the framework Eloquent?

```
Customer_loginToken::firstOrCreate(   
    array(   
         'customer_id' => $customer[0]->id_kunde,  
         'loginToken' => **'UUID()'**,  
         'loginIP' => $loginIP  
         )  
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's acutally pretty simple. Say you want to use GUIDs for you UUID, you can do so by the `com_create_guid` function.

Personally, I prefer the following shim for it as it adds the functionality if the PHP installation lacks it. It's somewhat the same. Also, `GUID()` is better than `com_create_guid()`.

Another thing to note here is that [MySQL describes THIS as format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). I am guessing that MySQL's `UUID` is nothing but a `GUID`.

```
function GUID()
{
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
    {
        return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
    }

    return sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
}

// Source http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php
```

Then

```
Customer_loginToken::firstOrCreate(   
array(   
     'customer_id' => $customer[0]->id_kunde,  
     'loginToken' => GUID(),  
     'loginIP' => $loginIP  
     )  
);
```

That should do it.

Another thing you can do, if you want to use the number format of the UUID: use the `uniqid` function. Exact same code, but the `GUID()` part is changed to `uniqid()`.

If nothing helps, you can write a function and put the value there.

However, remember that you won't be able to exact same value as MySQL as it's a completely random number.

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution! It works. But will this uuid never repeat? Is it globally unique？

Comment: Nope. The chances are really minute. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time

Comment: i have read your article and thanks for your help. This solution works, i have done :)

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)