# Is the value of Win32_NetworkAdapter GUID fixed?

Tags: c++, windows, wmi

I am using some values of **Win32_NetworkAdapter** to identify a PC and found a value named **GUID** which is globally unique for the connection.

But I am not sure whether the value would change if I reinstall the system. 
Can I use the value of **Win32_NetworkAdapter GUID** to identify a PC?

Thanks.

Comment: No, that's unlikely to work.  The GUID is probably generated randomly when Windows first discovers the device.  But `Win32_NetworkAdapter` *does* give you a unique identifier for the hardware: `MACAddress`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am curious about the mechanism of generating the value of GUID. How the Windows ensures the globally unique if two or more equivalent PCs install Windows at the same time?

Comment: It doesn't.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/39771/886887

Comment: Note that in this particular case, the GUID only needs to be locally unique, i.e., so long as *your* machine doesn't have two adapters with the same GUID, that's all that matters.  I don't know whether Windows tries to make the GUID globally unique or not.