# Using oracle sys_guid with column that has records

Tags: java, oracle, guid

I have a situation that I'm updating the code of an application that generates the primary code (GUID key)

From the code, I want to generate this key from  database using `sys_guid` function.

My question is:

The column already contains values and is unique. Is it possible that  `sys_guid` could return keys with same values that's generated from the application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time

Comment: "*Is is possible*?" - yes. Is it likely? - no.