# Delete a Placemark and save the whole kml minus the placemark into a new file

Tags: c#, sharpkml

My goal is to remove placemarks in a kml file read with sharpkml and save the xml as new kml.

What I tried

- RemoveChildren -> Not found
- AddUpdate with DeleteCollection -> Not working

And

```
using SharpKml.Base;
using SharpKml.Dom;
using SharpKml.Engine;

           
TextReader i_test = File.OpenText(@"test.kml");
KmlFile k_test = KmlFile.Load(i_test);
Kml l_test = k_test.Root as Kml;
var serializer = new Serializer();
if (l_test != null)
{
    foreach (var ort_u in l_test.Flatten().OfType<Placemark>())
    {
        Placemark p_u = ort_u;
        foreach(var einh in ort_u.ExtendedData.Data)
        {
            if (einh.Name == "teststring")
            {
                    var update = new Update();
                    update.AddUpdate(new DeleteCollection(){ p_u });
                    serializer.Serialize(l_test);
                    Console.WriteLine(serializer.Xml.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

None of them works.

How do I delete a Placemark using SharpKml and save the whole kml minus the placemark in a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... A `Placemark` is a `Feature`, and `Feature`s go in `Container`s... And in `Container`s there is an aptly named `.RemoveFeature()`... Sadly the method uses the `.Id` to find the `Feature`, but not all `Feature`s have an `Id`... But this we can solve. We set a temporary `Id` (`Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`) that is more or less guaranteed to be unique ([`Guid` are more or less guaranteed to be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39776/613130)), and we use this `Id` to remove the `Feature`.

Note that I had to add a `.ToArray()` in the `foreach`, because you can't modify a collection that you are going through, but with the `.ToArray()` we go through a "copy" of the collection, while we remove the elements from the original.

```
foreach (var placemark in kml.Flatten().OfType<Placemark>().ToArray())
{
    if (placemark.Name == "Simple placemark")
    {
        placemark.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        ((Container)placemark.Parent).RemoveFeature(placemark.Id);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(placemark.Name);
}
```

I've opened a [bug on the github of SharpKml](https://github.com/samcragg/sharpkml/issues/38) about this thing.

For saving:

```
using (var stream = File.Create("output.kml"))
{
    var ser = new Serializer();
    ser.Serialize(kml, stream);
}
```

Comment: Okay, that works. Yet my maps won't accept the file. Possible reasons?

Comment: @AureliusSchnitzler The serializer changes the file. I suggest you download Winmerge and compare the before-and-after. For example I've used the official google sample file, and `<open>1</open>` is changed to `<open>true</open>` and so on.

Comment: Use `File.Create` instead of `File.Write` to save the file. Bad examples in the github. The `File.Write` won't delete the file, it will simply overwrite starting from the first byte, so if there is already a bigger file, you'll overwrite the first part and leave the last part.