# Custom ConnectionId in SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a redis that stores user sessions. I want to run second instance of my app, but connection id can possibly match and cause problems

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with SignalR - but aren't those connection ID's [guids](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-5.0)? If so,  I think that's [random enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time) that you should spend more time on something more likely to happen, such as an earth ending asteroid that might cause some downtime for your app.

Comment: Use concurrent dictionaries to store the user along with a list of connections just in case the user logs into signalr multiple times