# Are contact IDs in agent/contact events out of Amazon Connect globally unique?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

For events generated by Amazon Connect, are contact IDs globally unique?

That is, can we expect contact IDs to be only unique within a specific instance of Amazon Connect?  Or rather, can we expect said contact IDs to be globally unique across *ALL* instances of Amazon Connect?

Answer (score 1):

ContactIDs are guids, so can be assumed to be unique across all Connect instances.

See [Is a GUID unique 100% of the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time)